# Join 2 tables userid, fuserid in 1 with 2 fields SQL

Tags: sql-server

Please tell me how to make a request. I need from 2 tables to choose identical values for the fields  [userid] and [fuserid].

```
SELECT a.userid, b.fuserid FROM users, fusers WHERE a.userid=457281 AND b.fuserid=457281
```

- blank field [userid][fuserid], although users have 2 values in the table fuserid not YET available values

```
SELECT a.userid, b.fuserid FROM users RIGHT JOIN fusers ON a.userid=457281 AND b.fuserid=457281
```

also produces empty field [userid][fuserid]

```
SELECT a.userid, b.fuserid FROM users LEFT JOIN fusers ON a.userid=457281 AND b.fuserid=457281
```

- issue junk box, for example

```
      [userid][fuserid]
      [457281][NULL]
      [457281][NULL]
      [391419][NULL]
```

- an extra field that is not necessary

```
SELECT a.userid, b.fuserid FROM users JOIN fusers ON a.userid=457281 AND b.fuserid=457281
```

- blank fields

```
(SELECT a.userid FROM users WHERE a.userid=457281) UNION (SELECT b.fuserid FROM fusers WHERE b.fuserid=457281)
```

- returns a single column with a value of 457281, in this case [userid]

But i need 2 tables were chosen identical entry fields userid and fuserid was shown in different columns so:

```
      [457281][457281] or
      [NULL][457281] or
      [457281][NULL]
```

Comment: Learn how ask question!!!  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Tag properly!!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server.  Which one is this???

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause is turning your `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to figure out what you want but here is my guess based on your desired results.

> [457281][457281] or
>         [NULL][457281] or
>         [457281][NULL]

```
Select a.userid, b.fuserid 
   From users u 
   Full Outer Join fusers f on f.fuserid = u.userid
   Where f.fuserid = 457281 or u.userid = 457281
```

Comment: Don't know why, but FULL OUTER JOIN is not executed, I tried, writes that the syntax error "syntax Error, consult the documentation"

Comment: @МаратШайхутдинов You don't know which dbms are you using????  Post your query that doesn't work.

Comment: #1064 - you Have an error in the query. Refer to the documentation for the version of MySQL on the subject of correct syntax near 'Full Outer Join f on f fusers.fuserid = u.userid Where f.fuserid' at line 3

Comment: You should change your tag from sql-server to mysql.  This post shows how to do it with mysql.